# Adobe LiveCycle Designer hide label description of textfield

Tags: adobe, sap-basis, livecycle-designer, adobe-form

I have textfield with datasource binding (from Interface). Those fields are only shown depending on another field "zkz", which holds a 'X' or is empty.

So the value of the fields are only displayed when the zkz field has an 'X' and this works good. But the label description of the fields are still there even when the field is empty. How to hide the description also?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which scripting language do you prefer, what do your scripts look like?

Comment: I dont use any script, just made settings on the adobe livecycle designer UI.

Comment: Then you will need to start using scripts, I'm afraid...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved via scripts only. Use the below steps:

1. Select your text field in the hierarchy
2. Call Script Editor by Ctrl-Shift-F5 if it's not visible
3. In the script editor select event *layout:ready*
4. Use following script to achieve conditional visibility of a field

   ```
   if( this.rawValue == 'value'){
   this.presence = "hidden";
   }
   else
   {
   this.presence = "visible";
   }
   ```

This Java script uses value of the same field as a condition, however you can use any other field on the form. Basic info can be get from [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/07/15/overview-on-scripting-languages-for-adobe-forms-beginners/) but better use Help of LiveCycle Designer.

Comment: Ok, that´s a good approach. I used if( this.rawValue === null){...} and the field is invisible when the value is null but is there a way to delete field so that even the empty space which the field holds will be deleted?

Comment: I don't think so. It is not possible by built-in functions and will require extensive scripting that will reduce to zero any use from such manipulations:)