# How to hide text in Adobe Form if user checks checkbox in selection screen?

Tags: forms, adobe, abap, sap-basis, livecycle-designer

I am fresher to Adobe form I want to print a text field if user click on the check box in the selection screen otherwise it will be hide that text field and print all other text in the Adobe form can anyone help me out...

Comment: Question just asked in the [SAP forum](https://answers.sap.com/questions/13702240/how-to-hide-unhide-the-text-field-in-the-adobe-for.html), so I guess that the current answer is not satisfactory, right? You may add comments here to ask for some clarification too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adobe LiveCycle Designer hide label description of textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063827/adobe-livecycle-designer-hide-label-description-of-textfield)

Answer (score 0):

You can use scripting for this issue.

I found a great article for this [here](https://www.berater-wiki.de/Mit_Scripting_Objekte_ausblenden_und_einblenden) (unfortunately its only in German).

But you can check the initial state of a variable for example like this:

```js
this.RABATT.rawValue == null || this.RABATT.rawValue == 0
```

or

```js
this.RABATT.rawValue == null || this.RABATT.rawValue == ""
```

For hiding the object in the form you can use:

```js
 if (DATE.rawValue == null)
 {
   this.presence = "hidden";
 }
 else
 {
   this.presence = "visible";
 }
```

Maybe this helps you a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You can directly add check
if checkbox is not initial.

Add your logic to print a text field.

Endif.